# What will be the DB Context code for executing this SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am new to `DbContext` and I am confused about how to join tables using `DbContext` - can someone tell me the code equivalent to this SQL?

```
Select * 
From AssignedCourses 
Join Students On StudentRollnumber = Students.StudentRollno 
Join Courses On Courses.CourseId = AssignedCourses.AssignedCourseId
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With EF you don't seldom need joins. Provided your relations are setup right in your backend, tools generate the models for you using navigational properties. Even without tools, it is easy to create models with navigatinal properties. That query could be written in different ways depending on your real needs. With navigational properties, generally you don't have the middle bridging table, but directly reference to Courses from Student (courses that a student is enrolled) or Students from Course (Students that are enrolled to that course). Assuming you want primarily the Students and the Courses they were enrolled to:

```
var result = ctx.Students;
// or preload them the Courses as well
var result = ctx.Students.Include(s => s.Courses);
```

Comment: there is no include function in context should i use select?

Comment: @UsmanArshad, what do you mean by there is no Include in context? You are talking about EF, right? It is not directly on context but DbSet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data BTW it is called eager loading. "Include is an extension method in the System.Data.Entity namespace so make sure you are using that namespace."

Comment: sorry for inconvenience i was misssing this reference using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Comment: Thanks for your help and time stay blessed

Answer (score 0):

you can use LINQ query :

from ac in db.AssignedCourses join s in Students on StudentRollnumber equals s.StudentRollno join c in Courses on c.CourseId equals ac.AssignedCourseId